# How to combine two sql queries such that the output of one query becomes a condition for another

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have two SQL queries

```
select a.name from Subjects a join Courses b on(a.id=b.subject) group by a.name having count(b.id) >=20;
```

this returns names of subjects with 20 or more course offerings.

```
select course from course_enrolments group by course having count(student)<20;
```

this returns the courses with less than 20 students enrolled in it.

How can I combine both the queires so that i can get names of subjects with 20 or more offerings and less than 20 students enrolled in it?

**Courses.id=Course_enrolment.course can be used to join table Courses and Course_enrolments**

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select a.name 
from Subjects a join Courses b on(a.id=b.subject) 
where b.id in (select course
    from course_enrolments 
    group by course 
    having count(student)<20
)
group by a.name 
having count(b.id) >=20;
```

Comment: also, I wanted output something like a.code||' '||a.name instead of just a.name. When I put this, it gives me an error saying a.code should be added to group by. When I add it to group by, it gives wrong output. How can i fix that?

Comment: i do something like group by a.code,a.name which returns wrong output

Comment: The order is important ... do group by a.name, a.code

Comment: i want a.code||' '||a.name. Shouldn't a.code come first?
anyway, it still gives wrong answer

Comment: put a.name, a.code in group by and then whatever other order in select clause.

Comment: Are there subjects with same name but different codes in your Subjects table?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
FROM (SELECT a.name,
        b.id as courseid
    FROM Subjects a
    JOIN Courses b
        ON a.id = b.subject
    GROUP BY a.name
    HAVING count(a.id) >= 20) s
JOIN (SELECT course
    FROM course_enrollments ce
    GROUP BY course
    HAVING count(*) < 20) c
ON c.course = s.courseid
```